# Methods to reduce regression underestimate and overestimate

Tags: regression, python, error, ensemble-learning

I'm new to a project and need to reduce the underestimate & overestimate cases in a regression problem. So far haven't gained enough domain knowledge. Underestimate is less tolerable than overestimate. The regressor is a emsembling model.

Need to do some research. Wondering do you have any suggestion that which directions can I research on to solve this problem?

Comment: You may consider splines if the dimensionality of predictors is small.

Comment: @stans, there are 50+ features, so I guess splines won't be a good choice?

Comment: How many observations do you have?

Comment: billions, @stans

Comment: Try gradient boosting, as proposed by Friedman.

Comment: Yes, we have tried those methods